# Why does this fadeOut function in JavaScript fail?

Tags: javascript

```
var d = document.getElementById("box");

function fadeOut(r, s) {
    if (!this instanceof Element) return false;
    this.style.opacity = ".90";
    var opacity = this.style.opacity;
    var t = setInterval(function() {
        if (!r) r = 500;
        opacity = (opacity) - s;
        if (opacity == ".0") return;
    }, r);
};

fadeOut.apply(d, [100, 5]);
```

It does not work. What went wrong?

Comment: I'd say - go for jQuery. Life's too short for re-inventing wheels. And think of the cross-browser campatibility...http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: I really want to know how to do it myself without using frameworks. If you know the answer, that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this isn't the answer you want, but if you are actually using this in a project then there are couple of things to note:

- You are only animating opacity – remember that IE<9 doesn't support this property.
- All current browsers that support opacity also support transitions (Firefox 3.X is the exception, but that's not going to hang around now 4 is out).

So, a much cleaner way to do this that works in all current browsers that yours would, would be to use CSS to set

```
-webkit-transition:opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
transition:opacity 0.6s ease-in-out;
```

Then in your JS, just change the opacity using

```
this.style.opacity = ".90";
```

It will animate as required, and as a rather large bonus it's hardware accelerated in some browsers (iOS at the moment).

Answer (score 1):

When you get to this line:

```
var opacity = this.style.opacity;
```

`opacity` is the string `".90"` *not* a reference to the `opacity` property of the `style` property of the element.

And returning from a function doesn't cancel an interval, you need `clearInterval` for that.

```
function fadeOut(r, s) {
    var self = this;
    if (!self instanceof Element) return false;
    self.style.opacity = ".90";
    var t = setInterval(function() {
        if (!r) r = 500;
        self.style.opacity = self.style.opacity - s;
        if (self.style.opacity == ".0") {
            clearInterval(t);    
        }
    }, r);
};
```

Also, full opacity is 1 and none is 0. You are reducing it by `s` each time and `s` is defined as `5`. Since you start by dropping to `.9`, you probably mean:

```
 fadeOut.apply(d, [100, .1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your opacity starts at 0.9.  Then you subtract 5 from it on every interval.  What this means is that the first time the interval runs you will try to set the opacity to the string "-4.1", which will fail to parse as a valid opacity value, so the set will be ignored.  And then you go around in circles.  Did you mean 0.05 instead of 5?  Or s/100 in the callback function?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var d = document.getElementById("box");
>
> function fadeOut(r, s) {
>     if (!this instanceof Element) return false;
>     this.style.opacity = ".90";
>     var opacity = this.style.opacity;
>     var t = setInterval(function() {
>         if (!r) r = 500;
>         opacity = (opacity) - s;
>         if (opacity == ".0") return;
>     }, r); };
>
> fadeOut.apply(d, [100, 5]);
> ```

There are many things wrong with this code.

First, CSS properties are strings, so your opacity addition line should be:

```
opacity = parseInt(opacity) - 0.05 + '';
```

Opacity is turned into an int, then adds negative 0.05, then is casted back into a string using `+ ''`

Secondly, `if (!r) r = 500;` should be defined outside the anonymous function.

You should have:

```
var d = document.getElementById("box");

function fadeOut(fadeScaler, hertz) {
    if (!this instanceof Element) return false;
    hertz = (!hertz) ? 60 : hertz; // Approx 60 hertz refresh rate

    var opacity = this.style.opacity
        opacity = ".9";

    var t = setInterval(
       function() {
         opacity = parseInt(opacity) - fadeScaler + '';

         if (parseInt(opacity) <= 0) 
           clearInterval(t);
       },
       Math.floor(1000 / hertz)); // 1000 miliseconds / hertz = refresh rate
};

fadeOut.apply(d, [.05]);
```

Pay more attention to the legibility and style of your code. An elegant coder is a smart coder.

Also, in IE opacity is the equivalent to the following:

```
this.filters.alpha.opacity=100
```

and it goes from 0 - 100.